# Is it possible for Chrome to communicate with external devices?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, usb

I work developing advanced browser based applications, using technologies like WebGL to create training and simulator tools.

Is it possible for such applications to access and interact with external devices connected to the Windows/Mac? If so what options are there?

A good example is: say we're creating a simulator for a surgical robot which is operated using a special joystick-type control. In a desktop application we could create a controller which has USB (serial port in the old days) and write custom code to interrogate this. But I don't know if browsers have any way to do the same.
In the days of plugins you could write a C++ plugin which acted as a bridge to the browser sandbox but this is not really an option in modern browsers.

What options exist, please? Our target is primarily Chrome though it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Yes, if the device is USB you could use -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USB

Comment: @Keith Make it an answer -- there is a gazillion of redundant questions about Jquery on Stack Overflow with 10 answers each, so a legitimate question like this could rightfully be answered with your comment and little else.